# git and html files

Tags: html, git

I would like to keep two versions of a **static** html file in my git repository. Both are basically identical, except for links for scripts, media etc (dev version vs. live version).

Right now I keep the dev version in repo, and overwrite the live version values manually on the live machine (=I have local git changes there). I am not happy with this setup, because there's manual labour for each push/pull.

What is the best flow for managing files that cannot be split into config/rest sections (like HTML)?

Answer (score 3):

You could...

- Remove the file from your repository and just manually populate it.  If it doesn't change very often, this works just fine.
- Remove the file from your repository, and generate it from a template via a post-merge script in `.git/hooks/post-merge` (this hook is run, for example, after `git pull`).
- Name the file after the branch or hostname or some other variable (e.g., `static.master.html` vs. `static.develop.html`, etc) and dynamically determine which one to use at runtime.

Those are some ideas.  I imagine other folks will contribute additional suggestions.

Comment: Cheers. I went with the last one: two distinct files + a symlink `static.html` on each machine. The symlink is not in repository. Syncing between the two files is manual, but at least no changes are required on the live machine.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the 2nd bullet point by [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks):

You could keep two copies in the repo (say it were your homepage) index.dev.html and index.prod.html. On the remote, your post-merge script could do something like:

```
cp -a index.prod.html index.html
```

or

```
truncate -s 0 index.html
cat index.prod.html >> index.html
```

Comment: FYI: Your sudo with redirection probably does not do what you think it's going to do (the `>>` redirection runs under the original user id, not root).  You could do `sudo sh -c 'cat index.prod.html >> index.html'`, or you could just stick with your `cp` command.

Comment: Good point. Plus, if you have authority to use git on the remote server, you surely have the permissions to edit these files so sudo isn't needed. I edited the posting to reflect it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem beside renaming is to keep the content of the both files in sync. So having dedicated files for the same reason only differing in one minor path is a lot of redundncy, if you change one, you have to think on updating the other as well.

OK, you stated that the HTML file is static, but here a line of PHP to generate the difference would solve our problem
   Achim